# Hassle with Javascript imports

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Most of the things I read online are either outdated or not precise enough.
I'm gonna try to expose my problem.
I was writing a d3 project comprise of 2 files, whose structure is like following

main.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="./KMeans.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    <!--Some code -->

    var kmeans = new KMeans();

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

KMeans.js :

```
class KMeans {
//class related stuff
}
```

Everything was working super fine, until I decided to add a new class named "Clustering" in a new file to be inherited by KMeans. The code became like this one :

main.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./KMeans.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    <!--Some code -->

    var kmeans = new KMeans();

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

KMeans.js :

```
import {Clustering} from './Clustering.js';

export class KMeans extends Clustering {
//class related stuff
}
```

Clustering.js :

```
export class Clustering {


}
```

And I keep getting this error :

```
ReferenceError: KMeans is not defined
```

For info, I'm not using Babel or any transpiler.

For the life of me, I can't understand a thing concerning the module management in JS. Could someone help me shed the light on what's wrong, please ?

Comment: Well where's the `import`?

Comment: KMeans.js, I just corrected the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a script is defined as a module the variables defined in it are no longer made public. So, you have two options.

**Option 1**

You can make both Clustering and KMeans regular, non-module files, and remove all `import` and `export` statements. This will solve your issue.

**Option 2**

You can move the final script tag to its own file and make it a module itself (maybe you can keep in inline and still make it a module but I'm not sure about this), and remember to import `KMeans` if you want to use it.